# Unique single values from list of tuple pairs?

Tags: python

From this data structure: `[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]` I am tying to get the unique values, or `[1,2,3,4,5]`. What's the easy solution here?

Comment: Is using an intermediate set ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `set` with list comprehension:

```
lst = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]

set(j for i in lst for j in i)
# {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: This is the first and most easy/pythonic way to solve the question. Great answer.

Comment: You could also use a set-comprehension: `{j for i in lst for j in i}`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `chain.from_iterable` from the `itertools` module. It's generally considered to be the idiomatic way to flatten a 2D iterable as opposed to a nested list comprehension. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) question.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> set(chain.from_iterable([(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]))
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

`chain.from_iterable` flattens the list and `set` keeps only unique values.

To convert back to a list, simply pass to the `list` constructor.

```
>>>list(set(chain.from_iterable([(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)])))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your expected output the order of the unique elements follows the order of appearance. One way  to do it would be (using an external library but the recipes are avaiable in the [`itertools`-recipes section](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)):

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import flatten, unique_everseen

>>> x = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]

>>> list(unique_everseen(flatten(x)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```